# c# 4.0 get class properties with (specified attribute and attribute.data)

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0, custom-attributes

I would like to get what properties of my class have an exact attribute with a concrete string.  I have this implementation (Attribute and Class):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class IsDbMandatory : System.Attribute
{
    public readonly string tableField;

    public IsDbMandatory (string tableField)
    {
        this.tableField= TableField;
    }
}

public Class MyClass 
{
    [IsDbMandatory("ID")]
    public int MyID { get; set; }
}
```

Then I get the property with the concrete attribute in this way:

```
public class MyService
{
   public bool MyMethod(Type theType, string myAttributeValue)
   {            
       PropertyInfo props = 
           theType.GetProperties().
                  Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(IsDbMandatory))); 
   }
}
```

But I need only the properties with concrete attribute `isDbMandatory` AND concrete string `myAttributeValue` inside.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var props = theType
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(
        prop => ((IsDbMandatory[])prop
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsDbMandatory), false))
            .Any(att => att.tableField == "blabla")
    );
```

Comment: What type is props ?   PropertyInfo[] ?  or only PropertyInfo (withour array).  I would like to strong type props to access its properties more clearly/easily.

Comment: @FerPt, it's `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>`. You could add a `.ToArray()` at the end to have a `PropertyInfo[]`.